# symfony 2.8 login error doesn't display

Tags: symfony

I have little problem. My symfony app after bad login doesn't show error mesage in login file ;/ . After typing good login & pasword everthing is ok, im logged & redirected to dashboard.

Sorry for my English:)

here is my controller

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * 
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $Request)
    {
        $Session = $this->get('session');



// Login Form
        if($Request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
            $loginError = $Request->attributes->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }else{
            $loginError = $Session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        if(isset($loginError)){
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $loginError->getMessage());
        }

        $loginForm = $this->createForm(new LoginType());



        return array(
            'loginForm' => $loginForm->createView()
        );
    }
```

here is block form_errors code in view file form_template.html.twig:

```
{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        {% for error in errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                <span> {{ error.message|trans }} </span>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :)

```
{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        {% for error in app.session.flashbag.get('error') %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                <span> {{ error|trans }} </span>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Execution pass into if(isset($loginError)){ ?